# How to pass a variable to another ASP.net page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Okay so I have some c# that generated href anchor tags styled as list items and throws it onto an aspx page like so;

```
html += "<a href='../InspectionView.aspx' class='list-group-item' id=''>Inspection ID: " + inspectionID + " - Due Date: " + inspDueDate + " - Inspector(s): Bob Williams <span style='min-width:75px' class='label label-primary pull-right'>" + status + "</span></a>";
```

Now this is in a loop, the variables are pulled from a SQL database and used to populate that html string.

Now, what I'm trying to do is have it so when the user clicks on one of the generated hrefs, and is redirected to the next page, the variable inspectionID is passed forward.  I thought there might be someway of storing it in the ID of the href tag but I dont know where to go from there.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The concept you are looking for is called "query string"

Comment: you need to build into that line the id to pass... at the end of the URL, add a ?inspectionID =  `insert value here`. If you have more than one value then after each key/value pair add "&nextValue="

Answer (score 4):

Add a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) parameter.

```
html += "<a href='../InspectionView.aspx?inspectionID='" + inspectionID + " class='list-group-item' id=''>Inspection ID: " + inspectionID + " - Due Date: " + inspDueDate + " - Inspector(s): Bob Williams <span style='min-width:75px' class='label label-primary pull-right'>" + status + "</span></a>";
```

For reading on the receiving page:

```
string inspectionID = Request.QueryString["inspectionID"];
```

See
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: in code request["variableName"];  assuming you are using C#

Comment: Thanks, that's great.

Answer (score 1):

a very simple way is to stick into a query string.  Since this isn't a server control it might be the only way to it.

something like...

```
html += "<a href='../InspectionView.aspx?InspectionID="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Inspection_ID.ToString())+"&anyotherQSField="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(anyotherQSFieldVariable) + "' class='list-group-item'> - Due Date: " + inspDueDate + " - Inspector(s): Bob Williams <span style='min-width:75px' class='label label-primary pull-right'>" + status + "</span></a>";
```

Then in InspectionView.aspx,get values with something like:

```
String strInspection_ID = Request.QueryString["InspectionID"];
```

You likely need to convert to string for this to work for the ID.
You dont have to use HttpUtility.UrlEncode for Inspection_ID but if you have other strings you want to use in QS that might contain spaces or other odd characters - it would be wise.